# Show lines that contain one, and only one, single-digit number

Tags: bash, grep

Using `grep`, how can I match lines that contain one, but only one, single-digit number?

Example of input file:

```
    SHELL=/bin/sh
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

    # m h dom mon dow user  command
    17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
    25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
    47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
    52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
    #
```

The output should be:

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

Comment: What did you try to get any output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep '\b[0-9]\b' file | grep -v '\b[0-9]\b.*\b[0-9]\b'
```

Output:

```
    25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

Comment: This works on the given sample data, but `\b` is a word boundary and does not distinguish between digits and other alphanumeric characters. So, it will consider `a6` to be a two-digit number, and fail.

Comment: This: `grep -P '\D\d\D' file | grep -vP '\D\d\D.*\D\d\D.*root'` should solve all problems: :-D

Answer (score 1):

To grep lines in a file that only contain one single digit, and only one single digit

Do this

```
grep -P '^\D*\d\D*$' file
```

The -P flag is to make a Perl expression

http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html

The expression itself is a regular expression

```
'^\D*\d\D*$'

'^'   = 'start of a line'
'\D*' = '0 or more non-digits'
'\d'  = '1 digit'
'\D*' = '0 or more non-digits'
'$'   = 'End of line'
```

---

Update:

Even if the question is answered and accepted, this solution might help someone who bumps into this question.

As mentioned by TomZych in the comments P is experimental, so I switched it with E, wich is --extended-expression.

And after the title was changed my previous answer is not what the OP wants.
So here is the new expression:

```
 grep -E '^([^0-9]|[0-9]{2,})*([0-9][^0-9]*)([^0-9]|[0-9]{2,})*$' file
```

Expression explained

```
'^' # start of line
```

We start with the first group.

```
([^0-9]|[0-9]{2,})* # The first group:

'( ... )' # what ever is inside the parantheses is in the group.
'*'       # means repeat this expression zero or more times.

'[^0-9]', '[0-9]' # means all digits from 0-9, but the 
'^'       # means NOT when its in the squared brackets.
'{2,}'    # means this expression 2 or more times
'|'       # means OR

# So what we want here is:
# Zero or more, (non-digits characters or two or more digits numbers)

# This will match anything untill we meet a single digit number.
```

Then there is the second group.

```
([0-9][^0-9]*) # second group:

# Here we want to match a single digit
'[0-9]'
# Followed by zero or more non-digits
'[^0-9]'

# This will match the single digit, the first group ran into.
# I use zero or more incase its the end of the line.
```

Then the 3. group wich is actually the first group again, zero or more times.

```
# Followed by 
'$' # End of line
```

This will match any line where there is only one single digit number.

```
1 abc 123
abc 1 123
abc 123 1
abc 1 abc
123 1 123
abc1abc

# will all match
```

Comment: This matches lines that contain a single-digit number and no other digits anywhere. Not what the OP wants. Try it on the sample data, it fails.

Comment: @TomZych  I see what he means now that the title has changed.

Comment: I assume you'll update it. Cleaner than my answer, but the docs for my version of grep (GNU grep 2.12) say -P is "highly experimental and `grep -P' may warn of unimplemented features". If it works, fine, but I'd be leery.

Comment: @TomZych I switched the -P with an -E. So now I cannot use \D or \d. The question is allready answered, but yea :) I like to play with and study regex

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks for calling it to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

This will match a single-digit number (SDN), as long as it's not at the
beginning or end of the line:

```
[^0-9][0-9][^0-9]
```

So, a fragile solution would be:

```
cat input |
grep '[^0-9][0-9][^0-9]' |
grep -v '[^0-9][0-9][^0-9].*[^0-9][0-9][^0-9]'
```

(Here, `cat input` stands in for anything piping data to the rest of it.
You can also give `grep` a filename.)

The first `grep` catches the lines with one or more SDNs, and the second
one excludes those with more than one.

However, it will fail to notice SDNs at the beginning or end of the
line, which can both miss lines and include ones we don't want. A simple
solution is to temporarily add a character to each end of each line.

```
cat input |
sed -r 's/(.*)/x\1x/' |
grep '[^0-9][0-9][^0-9]' |
grep -v '[^0-9][0-9][^0-9].*[^0-9][0-9][^0-9]' |
sed -r 's/^x(.*)x$/\1/'
```